# Which android bio-metric API we can use to implement Face unlock feature while accessing sensitive data

Tags: android, android-security, android-biometric-prompt

I want to implement Face unlock feature while accessing sensitive data of applications.
So is there any build it Api like fingerprint

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is in [blogPost1](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-fingerprintmanager-to-biometricprompt-4bc5f570dccd) and [blogPost2](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/10/one-biometric-api-over-all-android.html). They explain in great detail how to implement the AndroidX Biometric Library in your app and how the library works.

Essentially, once you implement the library, the framework will show the appropriate authentication UI based on which form factor a device supports -- whether face, fingerprint, etc.